# Pass a Hidden Field Variable to Order Notification Email

Tags: expresso-store, email, orders

I have a site that needs to have the Expresso Store order emails go to one of two locations.  What we will do is when the site is launched there will be a choice of store A or B.  Both are the same store but they have two locations for the sale centers. Once selected, wee want to collect a hidden variable or session variable that will allow us to control what email address is used for the order notification.  Is this possible and how can we do it?

Comment: Any idea why I can't pass a session variable to the Subject or BCC lines of Email Templates?  Trying this:

`
{exp:session_variables:get name='store_bcc_email'}
{exp:session_variables:get name='store_subject_location'}
`

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with all emails going to a default address you could add a hidden variable to the order data, possibly using two of Expresso's custom order fields.

Then on your server set up some email forwarders that forward to certain emails according to the hidden data variable, eg if the email contains the word "StoreA" send to email 1, if contains the word "StoreB" send to email 2.

Comment: I was almost doing same thing.  I tried using a session variable but apparently the subject and email parts of the Email Templates cant be done dynamically.  SO what I did was add a field into the email template body for LOCATION and then I may have the clients setup an email filter to look for it at each location.  That way even though it is sent to both, only the correct location would get to the inbox.